# property is filled, but empty in a method (linq select clause)

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I have the following code:

```
private IEnumerable<TrainScheduleViewModel> ListSelect(IQueryable<TrainSchedule> query, Page page)
{
    List<TrainScheduleViewModel> viewModels = query
        .Select(t => new TrainScheduleViewModel
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                ...
                DaysOfWeek = BuildDaysOfWeek(t.DaysOfWeek)
            })
        .Page(page)
        .ToList();

    return viewModels;
}

private string BuildDaysOfWeek(IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek)
{
    var daysOfWeekStr = string.Empty;

    return daysOfWeek.Aggregate(daysOfWeekStr,
        (current, dayOfWeek) => current + ";" + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int) dayOfWeek]);
}
```

In the debuger the `query` have one object and `DaysOfWeek` property is filled. But, in the `BuildDaysOfWeek` method the collection is empty. Can you explain me why?

Two images:
[image: debugger1]
[image: debugger2]

PS.1 This is mapping for property:

```
<bag name="DaysOfWeek" cascade="all-delete-orphan" table="`ScheduleOnDaysOfWeek`">
      <key column="`trainScheduleId`" not-null="true"/>
      <element  column="`dayOfWeek`" type="System.DayOfWeek" not-null="true" />
    </bag>
```

Comment: If you expand the variable it in the debugger, do the values appear?

Comment: @Baldrick: in the `BuildDaysOfWeek`? no

Comment: @user348173 `DaysOfWeek` property filled in every object from `query`? or it can be empty?

Comment: Which query provider are you using? For example, LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework. Or perhaps something else?

Comment: @Grundy: there are only one object. it can't be empty.

Comment: @hvd: It's Nhibernate. I have include mapping in the end of post.

Comment: I had a pretty similar bug. Try changing BuildDaysOfWeek(List<DateOfWeek>) and just in case when you call it: t.BuildDaysOfWeek.ToList(). Let me know if that works out.

Comment: @Andres: I tried, but not works.

Answer (score 0):

If `DaysOfWeek` a child collection? If so you need to [eager load](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/nhibernate-linq-eager-fetching.html) that table in order to do that type of projection e.g.

```
List<TrainScheduleViewModel> viewModels = query
    .Select(t => new TrainScheduleViewModel
                {
                    Id = t.Id,
                    ...
                    DaysOfWeek = BuildDaysOfWeek(t.DaysOfWeek)
                })
            .Page(page)
            .Fetch(x => x.DaysOfWeek)
            .ToList();
```

Or alternatively

```
DaysOfWeek = BuildDaysOfWeek(t.DaysOfWeek.ToList())
```

Comment: I tryed this, but not help.

Comment: @user348173 what did you try `ToList` or the `Fetch`?

Comment: @user348173 are you referencing `NHibernate.Linq`?

Comment: Only NHibernate and OracleDataAccess. I have a lot of queries, but problem only with this.

Comment: @user348173 `Fetch` is a LINQ extension, add this reference and it should work.